# how to detect Unity UNET errors?

Tags: unity, networking, unet, exceptions, error-management

I'm working on a simple multiplayer online game. and I use `UNET` and `Networkmanager`.

In my game I have some rooms and players that they can join to this rooms by connecting to specific `server.exe` file that I runned on a dedicated server.

My problem is when I use port 7777 for first server, if I run another server, then this error Appear :

> Cannot open socket on ip{*},and port{7777}

For now I solved this issue by building servers with specific ports.
for example in `server1.exe` I used port 7777 by default.
and `server2.exe` , 7778 and same for other servers .

But I want to do this automatically. I mean when the server recognize port 7777 is busy , then increase port number.

I want to know can I use `try catch` for this kind of errors ?
because I used `try catch` but it's not work.
I don't know how to use it. this is part of my code :

```
try
    {
        StartServer();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        networkPort++;
        //then change port number and run server again
    }
```

I just looking for a way that my servers run by choosing right port automatically.

Comment: Sorry about that, I wasn't paying close enough attention to my browser tabs & gave a Java based answer (which doesn't apply to your situation) instead of a Unity/C# related one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with another way that works very well.

For checking the port is free or not we can use `System.Net`.

and before Network Manager `StartServer()`, we have to check the current port is busy or not.

```
    int the_port = 7777;

    IPEndPoint[] list_all_ports = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveUdpListeners();

                foreach (IPEndPoint iep in list_all_ports)
                {
                    if (the_port == iep.Port)
                    {
                        the_port++;
                    }
                }

                //set the network port
                networkPort = the_port;
                StartServer();
```

For example if another server use 7777 then new server port will set 7778 automatically.